# polars: product of all columns except one in 2 LazyFrames

Tags: python, python-polars

I am learning polars, having come from pandas.

In pandas land, I frequently operate on 2 dataframes, each with a datetime index, and the same columns.

Example:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'time': pd.date_range('2023-01-01', periods=n, freq='1 min'),
    'foo': np.random.uniform(0,127, size=n).astype(np.float64),
    'bar': np.random.uniform(1e3,32767, size=n).astype(np.float64),
    'baz': np.random.uniform(1e6,2147483, size=n).astype(np.float64)
}).set_index('time')

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'time': pd.date_range('2023-01-01', periods=n, freq='1 min'),
    'foo': np.random.uniform(0,127, size=n).astype(np.float64),
    'bar': np.random.uniform(1e3,32767, size=n).astype(np.float64),
    'baz': np.random.uniform(1e6,2147483, size=n).astype(np.float64)
}).set_index('time')
```

To calculate the product of the columns I can do the following:

```py
df1 * df2
```

```
                    foo             bar             baz
time            
2023-01-01 00:00:00 8720.704791     1.632745e+08    2.276452e+12
2023-01-01 00:01:00 310.271257      3.375341e+08    2.195998e+12
2023-01-01 00:02:00 2936.646429     5.506997e+08    2.005228e+12
2023-01-01 00:03:00 12342.312737    3.383745e+08    3.779531e+12
2023-01-01 00:04:00 382.163185      1.371315e+08    1.529299e+12
```

The index remains the same, and each column in dataframe 1 is multiplied by its respective column in dataframe 2.

I am now trying to do the same with polars LazyFrames.

Here is the polars LazyFrame equivalent to my pandas dataframes above:

```py
df1 = pl.DataFrame(data={
    'time': pd.date_range('2023-01-01', periods=n, freq='1 min'),
    'foo': np.random.uniform(0,127, size= n).astype(np.float64),
    'bar': np.random.uniform(1e3,32767, size= n).astype(np.float64),
    'baz': np.random.uniform(1e6,2147483, size= n).astype(np.float64)
}).lazy()

df2 = pl.DataFrame(data={
    'time': pd.date_range('2023-01-01', periods=n, freq='1 min'),
    'foo': np.random.uniform(0,127, size= n).astype(np.float64),
    'bar': np.random.uniform(1e3,32767, size= n).astype(np.float64),
    'baz': np.random.uniform(1e6,2147483, size= n).astype(np.float64)
}).lazy()
```

I believe the correct way to operate on these 2 LazyFrames is to [`concat`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.concat.html), [`group_by`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.group_by.html) and then apply some aggregation.

However, whilst something like `sum` works as expected:

```py
pl.concat([df1, df2]).group_by('time').sum().sort('time').collect()
```

```
time                foo         bar             baz
datetime[ns]        f64         f64             f64
2023-01-01 00:00:00 117.758176  35887.733953    3.4859e6
2023-01-01 00:01:00 83.828093   32037.128498    3.3425e6
2023-01-01 00:02:00 158.950876  51900.065898    2.1312e6
2023-01-01 00:03:00 90.781075   41924.70712     3.4727e6
2023-01-01 00:04:00 156.831011  34252.423581    3.0899e6
```

I do not know how to perform a `product` aggregation

Things I have tried:

- `agg(col('*').mul(col'*'))`

```py
pl.concat([df1, df2]).group_by('time').agg(pl.col("*").mul(pl.col("*"))).sort('time').collect()
```

I'm not even sure what this is doing - it produces a list of values for each column

```
time                foo                         bar                     baz
datetime[ns]        list[f64]                   list[f64]               list[f64]
2023-01-01 00:00:00 [12359.923484, 114.893701]  [1.3056e8, 4.3358e8]    [1.2441e12, 3.0416e12]
2023-01-01 00:01:00 [1212.065713, 15767.846044] [8.9478e8, 8.6531e8]    [1.3674e12, 2.0145e12]
2023-01-01 00:02:00 [38.587401, 3658.818448]    [7.2488e8, 2.1755e8]    [3.6923e12, 1.6436e12]
2023-01-01 00:03:00 [298.835241, 1202.613949]   [7.9310e8, 5.6334e8]    [1.6880e12, 1.9158e12]
2023-01-01 00:04:00 [11931.488236, 697.035171]  [7.1008e7, 1.0676e9]    [2.1519e12, 3.2458e12]
```

How can I perform column-wise multiplication on my 2 dataframes, using `time` as the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [`.struct`](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/structs/) containing the "non-index" columns.

```py
df1.select("time", cols=pl.struct(pl.exclude("time")))
```

```py
shape: (5, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ time                ┆ cols                              │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                               │
│ datetime[ns]        ┆ struct[3]                         │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ {124.263949,27108.741665,1.2177e… │
│ 2023-01-01 00:01:00 ┆ {82.583389,6365.59054,1.5726e6}   │
│ 2023-01-01 00:02:00 ┆ {11.729725,14632.406993,1.3759e6… │
│ 2023-01-01 00:03:00 ┆ {84.397273,25237.331443,1.9678e6… │
│ 2023-01-01 00:04:00 ┆ {93.136133,13659.764971,1.9972e6… │
└─────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

And perform a left-join to align all the values:

```py
(df1.select("time", cols=pl.struct(pl.exclude("time")))
    .join(
       df2.select("time", cols=pl.struct(pl.exclude("time"))),
       on = "time",
       how = "left"
    )
)
```

```py
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ time                ┆ cols                              ┆ cols_right                        │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                               ┆ ---                               │
│ datetime[ns]        ┆ struct[3]                         ┆ struct[3]                         │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ {124.263949,27108.741665,1.2177e… ┆ {97.580405,5774.836603,1.6745e6}  │
│ 2023-01-01 00:01:00 ┆ {82.583389,6365.59054,1.5726e6}   ┆ {22.390398,16631.827323,1.4927e6… │
│ 2023-01-01 00:02:00 ┆ {11.729725,14632.406993,1.3759e6… ┆ {116.287397,29089.731203,1.6769e… │
│ 2023-01-01 00:03:00 ┆ {84.397273,25237.331443,1.9678e6… ┆ {70.481321,7588.344937,1.6139e6}  │
│ 2023-01-01 00:04:00 ┆ {93.136133,13659.764971,1.9972e6… ┆ {13.712869,27637.512573,1.7183e6… │
└─────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

You can then multiply the structs and [`.unnest()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest)

```py
(df1.select("time", cols=pl.struct(pl.exclude("time")))
    .join(
       df2.select("time", cols=pl.struct(pl.exclude("time"))),
       on = "time",
       how = "left"
    )
    .select("time", pl.col("cols") * pl.col("cols_right"))
    .unnest("cols")
)
```

```py
shape: (5, 4)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────┬──────────┬───────────┐
│ time                ┆ foo         ┆ bar      ┆ baz       │
│ ---                 ┆ ---         ┆ ---      ┆ ---       │
│ datetime[ns]        ┆ f64         ┆ f64      ┆ f64       │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════╪══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 12125.72637 ┆ 1.5655e8 ┆ 2.0389e12 │
│ 2023-01-01 00:01:00 ┆ 1849.074903 ┆ 1.0587e8 ┆ 2.3473e12 │
│ 2023-01-01 00:02:00 ┆ 1364.019211 ┆ 4.2565e8 ┆ 2.3072e12 │
│ 2023-01-01 00:03:00 ┆ 5948.43133  ┆ 1.9151e8 ┆ 3.1758e12 │
│ 2023-01-01 00:04:00 ┆ 1277.163612 ┆ 3.7752e8 ┆ 3.4318e12 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────┴──────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but I really don't know what to think about this - is this idiomatic polars? Surely not. I guess it's because I'm using an index (I read somewhere that in the original polars book it said ["Indexes are not needed! Not having them makes things easier - convince us otherwise!"](https://web.archive.org/web/20230117102825/https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/coming_from_pandas.html)). If I ensured the 2 dfs had the exact same number of rows (so no `group_by` needed) what would the idiomatic way of multiplying the columns by, and returning that and the `time` column?

Comment: I guess I'll ask another question. Let me construct that

Comment: Ha, I didn't even get to the "adding the `time` column back" - I couldn't even multiple 2 LazyFrames together! I've added a question here if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77732090/polars-multiply-2-lazyframes-together-by-column. Thanks!

Comment: Hunting around for answers I found you answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74834753/is-there-a-way-to-perform-lazy-operations-in-polars-on-multiple-frames-at-the-sa

The hoops we have to jump through in order to operate on multiple LazyFrames at once suggests this is a bit of an anti-pattern. Would you agree? Should I be using (non-lazy) DataFrames, or should I be changing the way I think about data?

Comment: @SteveLorimer horizontal concat for lazyframes [has just been merged.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/13139) (I think `.with_context` will be deprecated) - I'm not aware of any "syntax sugar" for this operation in Polars - perhaps there are some discussions on the Issues tracker? I haven't looked.

Comment: An answerer on my linked question in the comments above pointed to the issue tracker where Ritchie Vink himself said ["Data should be joined first before it can be compared"](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/10274#issuecomment-1664342380) - so I guess that settles it.